# Counterexamples to the Weak Unique Branch Hypothesis and Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

This question of mine comes from Woodin's "In Search of Ultimate-L" article, where they define the Weak Unique Branch Hypothesis and Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis. My confusion arises from remark $4.15$ and theorems $4.16$ and $4.17$ on pages $32$-$33$:

To quote the $3$-line paragraph directly above theorem $4.16$:

> We give two counterexamples to the attempt of formulating variations
> of the iteration hypotheses above by weakening the requirement that the
> iteration trees be $0$-strongly closed and maximal.

Now I read this in two different ways according to the theorems that come next:

First, I can take this to mean that both the Weak Unique Branch Hypothesis and Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis are wrong in the presence of a supercompact cardinal and we can build counterexamples which are even strongly maximal, let alone maximal.

Second, I can take this to mean that there has been a typo in the theorems or the definitions considered here, and the definitions of the Weak Unique Branch Hypothesis and Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis should have been stated for $0$-strongly closed strongly maximal iteration trees and the theorems should have given us just $0$-strongly closed maximal iteration trees. And I have a bit of evidence supporting some sort of a typo occurring, because in "Suitable Extender Models I", the same counterexample theorem produces totally non-overlapping trees, but you may take this with a grain of salt since I don't know whether totally non-overlapping is equivalent to strongly maximal or not.

All in all, I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what the correct case is and what is being implied here.

---

**EDIT I**: I am adding the relevant definitions and theorems for the sake of completeness, since I think some of them might not be super standard or well-known:

> Definition $4.13$ (Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis). Suppose that $(M, \delta)$ is a countable course premouse and $\pi: M\rightarrow V_\Theta$ is an elementary embedding. Then $(M, \delta)$ has an iteration strategy of order $(\omega_1+1)$ for $0$-strongly closed **maximal** iteration trees on $(M, \delta)$.

> Definition $4.14$ (Weak Unique Branch Hypothesis). Suppose that $(V_\Theta, \delta)$ is a countable course premouse and that $\mathcal{T}$ is a countable $0$-strongly closed **maximal** iteration tree on $(V_\Theta, \delta)$ of limit length. Then $\mathcal{T}$ has at most one cofinal wellfounded branch.

> Theorem $4.16$. Suppose there exists a supercompact cardinal. Then there exists an extender $E$ such that $\nu_E = (2^{2^{\kappa}})^{M_E}$, where $\kappa = \kappa_E$ and $M_E = \text{Ult}_0(V;E)$, and a $0$-strongly closed **strongly maximal** iteration tree $\mathcal{T}$ of length $\omega$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ has exactly two wellfounded cofinal branches.

> Theorem $4.17$. Suppose there exists a supercompact cardinal. Then there exists an extender $E$ such that $\nu_E = (2^{2^{\kappa}})^{M_E}$, where $\kappa = \kappa_E$ and $M_E = \text{Ult}_0(V;E)$, and a $0$-strongly closed **strongly maximal** iteration tree $\mathcal{T}$ of length $\omega^2$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ has only one cofinal branch and that branch is not wellfounded.

Remarks:

- First, I want to mention that the bold parts in the texts are the maximality conditions I was talking about in the main bulk of the post,
- and second, I want to mention that the theorems $4.16$ and $4.17$, that I have listed here, are weaker than what is written in the article, but they suffice for the purpose of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that the trees $\mathcal{T}$ referred to in Theorems 4.16, 4.17,
are not on $V$, but on $\mathrm{Ult}(V,E)$. In both cases we can form a tree $\mathcal{U}$ on $V$ given by $E$ followed by $\mathcal{T}$, but then $\mathcal{U}$ is *not strongly closed* (as it is not true that $\mathrm{strength}(E)=\mathrm{lh}(E)=$ an inaccessible cardinal (in $V$)).

However, I don't see how Theorem 4.17 itself violates  the strengthening of the Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis, because (i) 4.17 doesn't say that the branches at the intermediate limit stages are unique wellfounded branches, and (ii) the tree is on $V$, not a countable elementary substructure of some $(V_\theta,\delta)$. (It does directly contradict  CBH, the Cofinal Branches Hypothesis.) There is related material in Neeman-Steel "Counterexamples to the unique and cofinal branches hypotheses". In the tree there which is a counterexample to CBH (the tree $\mathcal{U}$ constructed at the end), the tree has length $\omega^2$, and consists of a single extender followed by an $\omega$-sequence of alternating chains, hence at each intermediate limit stage $n\times\omega$, there are exactly 2 cofinal branches. But in their construction, they say both of these branches give wellfounded models (in fact they are the same model). So it is not clear to me that the tree didn't just follow the wrong iteration strategy. Secondly, suppose that the tree $\mathcal{T}$ referred to in 4.17 does have unique wellfounded branches at intermediate stages. Then one might try to form a countable elementary hull $M$ of some $(V_\Theta,\delta)$ so that the picture reflects down to $M$. This would work fine if e.g. the intermediate stages are all alternating chains. But if they are instead complex enough that they have many cofinal branches, then uniqueness of wellfounded branches doesn't seem to automatically pass down to $M$. So as far as I can tell, this also needs to be dealt with.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I have a few questions. First, I don't understand your first assertion: I was under the impression that these theorems build premice that have bad trees on them, does it matter that $\mathcal{T}$ is not on $V$?$(1)$ My second question is about the abbreviation SBH: is it the same weak iteration hypothesis I mentioned above?$(2)$

Comment: I also understand your first objection to theorem $4.17$, but it seems to me that since as you say, the intermediate branches all have isomorphic end models, then since this agreement continues for all $n$, then the ultimate models on the cofinal branches they induce should be isomorphic as well, and they both will be ill-founded, and so there is no strategy after all?$(3)$

Comment: Also, I think I don't understand your second obejction: since we ultimately know there is at most one cofinal branch, it suffices to just include that in our Skolem hull, no? Because then the countable collapse $M$, can never have other cofinal branches and the one branch that we gave it, is ill-founded. $(4)$

Comment: Also, what do you think about $4.16$, do you think that that theorem is a counterexample? And all in all, would you say that the situation we have here is intended to present counterexamples in the presence of suprecompact cardinals?$(5)$ [Sorry for all of these questions; this stuff is really confusing for me. I have added numbers right after each question, for better reference if you'd kindly choose to answer them.]

Comment: (2) Sorry, where I wrote "SBH" I meant "Weak $(\omega_1+1)$-Iteration Hypothesis", which I've now changed (I don't recall whether SBH is usually this or some variant). (1) Note that 4.14 is defined for trees $\mathcal{T}$ on some $(V_\Theta,\delta)$. If we define 4.14' as the same thing but striking out "$0$-strongly closed maximal" (maybe replacing it with "which uses only short extenders and is strongly maximal*", where strongly maximal* is a natural variant of strongly maximal for more general trees), then Theorem 4.16 gives a counterexample to 4.14'...

Comment: ...using $\mathcal{U}=$ the tree $E$ followed by $\mathcal{T}$, but modified so that the base model is some $(V_\Theta,\delta)$, with $\Theta$ large enough, instead of base model $V$.

Comment: But 4.16 does not provide a counterexample to 4.14 in this way, as $\mathcal{U}$ is not strongly closed (because its first extender $E$ violates "strongly closed"), and $\mathcal{T}$ is not on $V$. For 4.17 it is likewise, regarding the first extender $E$ violating "strongly closed", but now for 4.13 it's supposed to be a tree on some countable elementary $M\to (V_\Theta,\delta)$, and there are the issues (i) and (ii) I discussed above.

Comment: (3) We have the intermediate trees $\mathcal{T}_n=\mathcal{T}\upharpoonright n\times\omega$, with two distinct cofinal branches $b_n,c_n$, and $M^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{b_n}=M^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{c_n}$. Write $M_{n+1}=$ this model, and $M_0=V$. Say $b_n$ is the branch used in $\mathcal{T}$. So the direct limit of the models $M_n$ under the iteration maps $i^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{b_n}$ is illfounded. But we can have $i^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{c_n}\neq i^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{b_n}$ (see the Zipper Lemma in Outline)...

Comment: I see your point, but this makes it confusing for me. If these aren't counterexamples to WUBH and the other hypothesis, then what are they showing?

Comment: ...We can also define a tree $\mathcal{U}$ which is just like $\mathcal{T}$, except it uses $c_n$ instead of $b_n$ (since $M^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{b_n}=M^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{c_n}$, this makes sense). Then (also considering more details of the construction) $\mathcal{U}$ also has a unique branch $c$, and $M^{\mathcal{U}}_c$ is the direct limit of the $M_n$'s under the iteration maps $i^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{c_n}$. Since these can differ from $i^{\mathcal{T}_n}_{b_n}$, the direct limit model can be different, and so maybe wellfounded. So maybe the strategy should have chosen the $c_n$'s.

Comment: (4) There might be uncountably many cofinal branches at an intermediate stage (although the tree itself has only countably many nodes). It is not obvious how to record witnesses to the illfoundedness of all the branches into a countable elementary hull. So maybe there are some branches which, although they give an illfounded model $V'$ for the tree on $V$, give a wellfounded one $M'$ for the tree on $M$. (We will get that $M'$ embeds into $V'$, but a wellfounded model embedding into an illfounded one is of course no problem.)

Comment: @(3), I see. I was under the impression that since you said at intermediate stages we have the same models, then probably the embeddings were equal. But I guess not. (Also please ignore my previous comment to move this to chat, it was a missclick) @(4) I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: (5) Yes, 4.16 gives a counterexample to UBH (the stronger version) from a supercompact. (But not to weak-UBH, i.e. 4.14.) And, yes, I think it's supposed to illustrate counterexamples to stronger versions of the hypotheses than those stated in 4.13 and 4.14 (specifically dropping the "strongly closed" requirement), though as I said, due to issues (i) and (ii), I'm unclear about the connection between 4.17 and such a variant of 4.13.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: No problem! ---